# AndroidStudio C++ Compiler Options

Tags: c++, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

While trying to run my code, which is include C++ files I get the following error -

```
Error:(32, 2) error: This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
```

How it can be solved? This is my first project that involved with C++ files.

Comment: You must enable "the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options."

Comment: Learning C++ on Android is a very bad idea. Anyway, you must somehow make your IDE pass the correct flags to the compiler in order to use C++11 features and/or use a compiler for which C++11 is no longer experimental. I hear there's some "Customize C++ Support" button or dropdown menu somewhere in the UI which can do that for you.

Comment: I know i have to use -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 but how can i config that?

Comment: There are multiple ways of building native code from Android Studio, and I don't see any mention of which one you're using. If you've got an Android.mk file you could add any flags you want in there to `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS`. Otherwise you probably need to use some sort of `cppFlags` property in your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

I have rebuild my project and use C++11 instead of ToolChain Default in Customize C++ Support page.
I think it is a dirty way for solving this problem.

Comment: Maybe *'ToolChain Default'* is not the perfect way to present one of the choices, but this is the clean way to deal with this problem. C++ has different not exactly compatible 'modes', e.g. C++11 and C++13, and it is your responsibility to choose the appropriate dialect.

Answer (score 0):

In app's build gradle under android -> defaultConfig you can add / change the following

```
externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-std=c++11"
        }
    }
```